# D3 Scatterplot: Tooltip appears on initial load, but disappears after filter updated using dropdown

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

In this D3 code, I have plotted a scatterPlot, and  the data gets filtered based on the dropdown selection. I have added tooltips also for this scatter plot. On initial load I see that tool tip is working fine. However, after the dropdown box gets selected, the graph is updated and thereafter tooltip stops working.

I tried to put .on mouseover event in the update function also, but that also doesnt work, and in fact causes problem that SelectAll option displays only ne set of data. Appreciate any help in pointing me to the problem with the code.
    I have commented this out in the update function so that graph would show what I meant to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MathsVsEnglishScore</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<style>
        body {
            font: 15px sans-serif;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .dot {
            stroke: none;
        }
        .tooltip {
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 12px;
            width:  auto;
            height: auto;
            pointer-events: none;
            background-color: white;
        }
         </style>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Initialize a select button -->
<p><font size = "5px"><b>Analysis of Maths And English Score</b></font></p>
<p><b><font color = "172E8E">Gender: <select id="selectButton"></select></font></b></p>
<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->

<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
<a href='indexNew.html'><b>Back</b></a>;
<!-- Color Scale -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>

<script>


// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var canvas  = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
var svg = canvas
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aknemani/test-repo/master/exams100.csv", function(data) {

    // List of groups (here I have one group per column)
    var allGroup = d3.map(data, function(d){return(d.gender)}).keys().sort()
allGroup.push('SelectAll')
    // add the options to the button
    d3.select("#selectButton")
      .selectAll('myOptions')
        .data(allGroup)
      .enter()
        .append('option')
      .text(function (d) { return d; }) // text showed in the menu
      .attr("value", function (d) { return d; }) // corresponding value returned by the button

    // A color scale: one color for each group
    var myColor = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(allGroup)
      .range(d3.schemeSet2);

    // Add X axis --> it is a date format
    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([ 0, width]);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(10));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 200])
      .range([height, 0]);
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

            svg.append("text")             
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + (height+30) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Maths Score");

        svg.append("text")             
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (-25) + " ," + (height/2) + ") rotate(-90)")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Reading And Writing Score");

            var tooltip = d3.select("#my_dataviz").append("div")
                  .attr("class", "tooltip")
                  .style("opacity", 0);

            // tooltip mouseover event handler
              var tipMouseover = function(d) {
                  var color = "red";//colorScale(d.manufacturer);
                  var html  = d.gender + "<br/>" +
                              "<b>" + d.mathScore + "</b> Math, <br/>" 
                              + "<b>" + d.readingScore + "</b> Reading, <br/>"
                              + "<b>" + d.writingScore + "</b> Writing";

                  tooltip.html(html)
                      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 15) + "px")
                      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px")
                    .transition()
                      .duration(200)
                      .style("opacity", .9)
              };
              // tooltip mouseout event handler
              var tipMouseout = function(d) {
                  tooltip.transition()
                      .duration(300) // ms
                      .style("opacity", 0); // don't care about position!
              };                  

    // Initialize line with first group of the list
    var dataFilter = data.filter(function(d){return d.gender==allGroup[0]})
    var scatterGraph = svg
      .append('g')
        .selectAll('circle')
        .data(dataFilter)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d){return x(d.mathScore);})
        .attr('cy', function(d){return y(Number(d.readingScore)+Number(d.writingScore));})
        .attr('r', function(d){return Number(5);})
        .style("fill", myColor(allGroup[0]))
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .on("mouseover", tipMouseover)
        .on("mouseout", tipMouseout);

    // A function that update the chart
    function update(selectedGroup) {
        var tooltip = d3.select("#my_dataviz").append("div")
                  .attr("class", "tooltip")
                  .style("opacity", 0);

        var tipMouseover = function(d) {
                  var color = "red";//colorScale(d.manufacturer);
                  var html  = d.gender + "<br/>" +
                              "<b>" + d.mathScore + "</b> Math, <b/>" 
                              + d.writingScore + "</b> Writing";

                  tooltip.html(html)
                      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 15) + "px")
                      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px")
                    .transition()
                      .duration(200)
                      .style("opacity", .9)
              };
              // tooltip mouseout event handler
              var tipMouseout = function(d) {
                  tooltip.transition()
                      .duration(300) // ms
                      .style("opacity", 0); // don't care about position!
              };
        var dataFilter = data.filter(function(d){return d.gender==selectedGroup})
        svg
        .append('g')
        .selectAll('circle')
        .data(dataFilter)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d){return 0;})
        .attr('r', function(d){return Number(0);})
        .attr('cy', function(d){return height;})
        .style("fill", myColor(selectedGroup))  
        .style("stroke", 'black')
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attr('cx', function(d){return x(d.mathScore);})
        .attr("r", function(d,i) { return 5; })
        .attr('cy', function(d){return y(Number(d.readingScore)+Number(d.writingScore));})
        //.on("mouseover", tipMouseover)
        //.on("mouseout", tipMouseout);

    }

    // When the button is changed, run the updateChart function
    d3.select("#selectButton").on("change", function(d) {
        canvas.selectAll('circle').remove();
        var selectedOption = d3.select(this).property("value")
        if(selectedOption == 'SelectAll') 
        {
            allGroup.forEach(function(element) {
            console.log(element);
            selectedOption = element;
            update(selectedOption);
                });
        }
        // run the updateChart function with this selected option
        else
        {
           update(selectedOption);
        }

    })

})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `update` function you have the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events commented, if you remove the comments it throws an error, and that is because you are trying to add event listeners to a transition, or better, you should enter those lines before setting the transition. Something like this:

```
     ...
    .attr('cy', function(d){return height;})
    .style("fill", myColor(selectedGroup))  
    .style("stroke", 'black')
    .on("mouseover", tipMouseover)
    .on("mouseout", tipMouseout)
    .transition().duration(1000)
    ...
```

But when I tried your code, I noticed a couple of problems in your code.

First, your are doing `append` on each call to that function, so a tooltip div will be created every time the `update` function gets called.

```
function update(selectedGroup) {
    var tooltip = d3.select("#my_dataviz").append("div")
              .attr("class", "tooltip")
              .style("opacity", 0);
```

I would add it on the visualization initialization and keep a reference to it, then, use that reference to show/hide it.

The same happens with the `tipMouseover` and `tipMouseout` functions, you are declaring them two times, try not to create duplicate code, so if you create once, and keep a reference to them.

Finally, you are also repeating the code to append the circles, you can improve that by using a common function. I created [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fnp5vgyh/) jsfiddle with the recommendations, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It didnt only fix my problem, but you also showed me how to better program by reducing the code duplication. Really appreciate.